# Extracking data from a .xls email attachment and inserting into a database

Tags: python, sql, azure, azure-logic-apps, power-automate

I am trying to extract data from an .xls table that is an attachment to an email.  I would then like to insert that data into a sql table. I have the trigger working and am getting the attachment.  I just seem to be running into a brickwall from there. Any thoughts?  One wrench is the file format has 3 blank rows to start then a row of headers, then rows of data.

Currently the tool i am trying to use is azure logic apps.  I am not super comfortable in writing custom python code to do this but I am willing to give it a shot.

Comment: Mate, provide more information!!! It’s simple! Screenshots, error messages, etc. too hard to help at present.

Answer (score 0):

After reproducing from my end, I could able to achieve expected results after following the below.

Initially, I have sent the attachment to my sharepoint as below and then used `List rows present in a table` action of Excel connector.

[image]

Even though my Excel looked like below after retrieving the results from Excel Connector, my logic apps read only the table and ignored the first row.

[image]

[image]

```
[
  {
    "@odata.etag": "",
    "ItemInternalId": "d18b",
    "Name": "John",
    "Section": "A"
  },
  {
    "@odata.etag": "",
    "ItemInternalId": "ede",
    "Name": "Mark",
    "Section": "D"
  },
  {
    "@odata.etag": "",
    "ItemInternalId": "6a37",
    "Name": "David",
    "Section": "A"
  },
  {
    "@odata.etag": "",
    "ItemInternalId": "8a99a",
    "Name": "Hailey",
    "Section": "B"
  },
  {
    "@odata.etag": "",
    "ItemInternalId": "8ca",
    "Name": "Bruno",
    "Section": "C"
  }
]
```

Next you can send the data to SQL as below.

[image]

*Results:*

[image]

[image]